# Model returns near perfect PR-AUC score but other metrics seem fine. Is my model overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance, overfitting

I am currently working on a very imbalanced dataset:

- 24 million transactions (rows of data)
- 30,000 fraudulent transactions (0.1% of total transactions)

The dataset is split via Year, into three sets of training, validation and test. I am using XGBoost as the model to predict whether a transaction is fraudulent or not. After tuning some hyperparameters via optuna, I have received such results

**Model parameters and loss**

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score, precision_recall_curve, auc, average_precision_score, ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
evalset = [(train_X, train_y), (val_X,val_y)]

params = {'lambda': 4.056095667860487, 'alpha': 2.860539790760471, 'colsample_bytree': 0.4, 'subsample': 1, 'learning_rate': 0.03, 'n_estimators': 300, 'max_depth': 44, 'random_state': 42, 'min_child_weight': 27}
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params, scale_pos_weight = estimate, tree_method = "gpu_hist")  
model.fit(train_X,train_y,verbose = 10, eval_metric='logloss', eval_set=evalset)
```

```
[0] validation_0-logloss:0.66446    validation_1-logloss:0.66450
[10]    validation_0-logloss:0.45427    validation_1-logloss:0.45036
[20]    validation_0-logloss:0.32225    validation_1-logloss:0.31836
[30]    validation_0-logloss:0.23406    validation_1-logloss:0.22862
[40]    validation_0-logloss:0.17265    validation_1-logloss:0.16726
[50]    validation_0-logloss:0.13003    validation_1-logloss:0.12363
[60]    validation_0-logloss:0.09801    validation_1-logloss:0.09230
[70]    validation_0-logloss:0.07546    validation_1-logloss:0.06987
[80]    validation_0-logloss:0.05857    validation_1-logloss:0.05278
[90]    validation_0-logloss:0.04581    validation_1-logloss:0.04001
[100]   validation_0-logloss:0.03605    validation_1-logloss:0.03058
[110]   validation_0-logloss:0.02911    validation_1-logloss:0.02373
[120]   validation_0-logloss:0.02364    validation_1-logloss:0.01859
[130]   validation_0-logloss:0.01966    validation_1-logloss:0.01472
[140]   validation_0-logloss:0.01624    validation_1-logloss:0.01172
[150]   validation_0-logloss:0.01340    validation_1-logloss:0.00927
[160]   validation_0-logloss:0.01120    validation_1-logloss:0.00752
[170]   validation_0-logloss:0.00959    validation_1-logloss:0.00616
[180]   validation_0-logloss:0.00839    validation_1-logloss:0.00515
[190]   validation_0-logloss:0.00725    validation_1-logloss:0.00429
[200]   validation_0-logloss:0.00647    validation_1-logloss:0.00370
[210]   validation_0-logloss:0.00580    validation_1-logloss:0.00324
[220]   validation_0-logloss:0.00520    validation_1-logloss:0.00284
[230]   validation_0-logloss:0.00468    validation_1-logloss:0.00253
[240]   validation_0-logloss:0.00429    validation_1-logloss:0.00226
[250]   validation_0-logloss:0.00391    validation_1-logloss:0.00205
[260]   validation_0-logloss:0.00362    validation_1-logloss:0.00191
[270]   validation_0-logloss:0.00336    validation_1-logloss:0.00180
[280]   validation_0-logloss:0.00313    validation_1-logloss:0.00171
[290]   validation_0-logloss:0.00291    validation_1-logloss:0.00165
[299]   validation_0-logloss:0.00276    validation_1-logloss:0.00161
```

**Learning curve**
[image: Learning curve]

**F1 and PR AUC scores**

```
F1 Score on Training Data : 0.8489783532267853
F1 Score on Test Data : 0.7865990990990992
PR AUC score on Training Data : 0.9996174980952233
PR AUC score on Test Data : 0.9174896435002448
```

**Classification reports of training/testing sets**

```
Training report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00  20579668
           1       0.74      1.00      0.85     25179

    accuracy                           1.00  20604847
   macro avg       0.87      1.00      0.92  20604847
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00  20604847

Test report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00   2058351
           1       0.95      0.67      0.79      2087

    accuracy                           1.00   2060438
   macro avg       0.98      0.83      0.89   2060438
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00   2060438
```

**Confusion matrices (1st is training set, 2nd is testing set)**

[image: Training matrix]

[image: Test matrix]

I see that my PRAUC of the training dataset is nearly 1 and it has perfect recall score, so I suspect that my model is overfitting. However, when I test these results on a validation set and testing set, the results are not too far off, and still achieve what I believe to be decent scores.

I would love to hear your thoughts on this, and thank you all in advance and I would appreciate any response!